# Stopover in Dubai and import laws

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dubai, emirates, import-taxes

A few friends and I are travelling from Ireland to Japan in a month and we have a 4-hour stopover in Dubai both ways (flights are all with Emirates). According to the Dubai Customs website "Original engravings, prints, lithographs, sculpture and statues in any material" are banned items, including for transit. Does this mean that we cannot purchase figures/posters in Japan and bring them back to Ireland? I can't seem to find anything on the Emirates website that states this, only on the Dubai Customs website.

https://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/eServices/ServicesForIndividuals/ViewCustomsInformation/Pages/Prohibited-and-Restricted-Goods.aspx

> There are certain goods that cannot be imported, exported **or transited** or that require permits from the competent authority.

(emphasis added)

https://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/eServices/ServicesForTravellers/CustomsDuties/Pages/PermittedItems.aspx

In addition, the [Dubai Airport](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/security-customs) webpage only mentions printed materials that contradict Islamic teachings, nothing about statues or prints.

Comment: Did you look for information on the National Media Council?  They can issue permits for "Printed books, newspapers and similar products, Work Art, collectors “Pieces and Antiques”" according to your first link.

Answer (score 1):

Customs is about controlling importation of goods *into* the country. Which, unless you pass through Immigration and Customs, you won't be doing. Since you just have a 4-hour layover, and your luggage will never leave airside, being transferred from one Emirates plane to another, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: But the list of banned goods notes that it concerns items that may not be "imported, exported *or transited"* (emphasis added).  I'm afraid I have to downvote this answer.